# Recursive problem with mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, recursion, mongoose

I'm calling this function to search through my collection
and check whether player B is under player A or not

```
function checkIfDownline(playerA,playerB){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        teamDataModel.find({owner:playerA}).then((result)=>{
            if (result.length == 0){
                resolve(0)
            }else{
                result[0].teams.map(z=>{
                    if (z.subPlayer == playerB){
                        // If player is exists under you
                        console.log(true)
                        resolve(1)
                    }else{
                        // If player does not exist under you
                        resolve(checkIfDownline(z.subPlayer,playerB))
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Here is my schema

```
    owner:String,
    teams:[
        {
            subPlayer:String
        }
    ]
```

The general idea is that Player B could be under Player C who is under Player A , which would then look like this

```
{
    owner:"Player A",
    teams:[
        {
            subPlayer:"Player C"
        }
    ]
}
{
    owner:"Player C",
    teams:[
        {
            subPlayer:"Player B"
        }
    ]
}
```

This would then mean Player B is under Player A.I am able to check whether Player B is under Player A correctly . **However** when there is another player,Player D, under player C , the function is unable to check whether player D is under player A correctly. I am unable to figure the problem , please help tq ^^

Comment: you should use the [`aggregate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) method and perform such query in the server ... in a few months, you would not want to download all the data in the database to perform such checks...

Comment: @balexandre Thank for you reply , can you explain in a little bit more depth on how I could use aggregate to tackle this problem?